# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "630df09c25324c5f7af17dd9\n\n" (type string) at path "_id.. " for model "User"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

I have created this method to fetch the data of single User. My route for this method is this:

```
router.get("/userInfo/:id", getUserData);
```

But when i tried to check this end point on Postman I got this error again and again reason:

```
BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer.
```

The same code above in another method is working properly but here this is not working correctly i don't why and where is problem in my code. I have tried this find method too:

```
findOne ({_id: req.params.id})
```

And this did not work too and returns user Null information.

My Mongodb user id is this  `_id: 630df09c25324c5f7af17dd9`

```
//users.js 
const User = require("../Models/userSchema");
exports.getUserData = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    console.log(user);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "User details",
      user,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
``Routes/userRoute.js``
const router = require("express").Router();
const {
  getUserData,
} = require("../Controllers/users");
router.get("/userInfo/:id", getUserData);
module.exports = router;

//Main Server javascript file  index.js
const usersRoute = require("./Routes/usersRoute");
app.use("/api/v1", usersRoute);

//http://localhost:8800/api/v1/userInfo/630df09c25324c5f7af17dd9
```

Complete Error in server console:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "630df09c25324c5f7af17dd9\n\n" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"
    at model.Query.exec (D:\React Projects\social-media-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4803:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (D:\React Projects\social-media-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4902:15)       
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"630df09c25324c5f7af17dd9\\n\\n"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '630df09c25324c5f7af17dd9\n\n',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
      at new BSONTypeError (D:\React Projects\social-media-app\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
      at new ObjectId (D:\React Projects\social-media-app\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:67:23)
      at castObjectId (D:\React Projects\social-media-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (D:\React Projects\social-media-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:246:12)     
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (D:\React Projects\social-media-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1192:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (D:\React Projects\social-media-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1635:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (D:\React Projects\social-media-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1623:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (D:\React Projects\social-media-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1599:20)
      at cast (D:\React Projects\social-media-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:344:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (D:\React Projects\social-media-app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5227:12),    
  valueType: 'string'
}
```

Comment: If you get rid of the newlines (`"\n"`) in your string, does it work then?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `req.params.id` contains newlines unless they are explicitly passed in the URL (`GET /userInfo/630df09c25324c5f7af17dd9%0a%0a`). You should take a look at the client code that's performing the request.

Comment: Can you post the code or url you are calling to get user data?

Comment: Now i posted my complete code and i don't know from where in the server with my string id this ("\n") line are being concated or created.  i am not passing anywhere in my code these newlines in req.params.id

Comment: Its because "630df09c25324c5f7af17dd9\n\n" is not a valid ObjectId. There is something wrong with your client side code that is adding the new lines in the URL. 
Try the url without the new line(\n\n) `/userInfo/630df09c25324c5f7af17dd9` in Postman which I think will not throw the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the frontend code, not the backend code.

If you put the data as a value of some form field, make sure that the quotes around it are on the same line.

eg. (this is wrong)

```
value="
{{ object._id }}
"
```